# fade 4 Alphabets of a Word and Retain one alphabet "H"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am not able to fade the 4 alphabets "ello" from the word "Hello" when the word is zooming out.

What i need is, when i reach step number 6 and 7 from my below code, the texts "e" "l" "l"  "o" should fade out, but only the alphabet "H" should go towards the left top corder
  // 6. zooms out to 200% heading towards left top corner,
// 7. Fades out when reaching the logo

Js:

```
 // 3. Page load completes - the text "hello",
    // has come to center with zoom 800%
    $("#hello").animate({
      zoom: "800%",
      left: window.innerWidth / 2
    }, 3000, function() {
      // 4. Pause for 3 seconds
      $(this).delay(3000)
      // 6. zooms out to 200% heading towards left top corner,
      // (logo position) 
      // 7. Fades out when reaching the logo 8. Logo appears
      .animate({
        zoom: "200%",
        left:0
      }, 3000, function() {
        $(this).fadeOut()
      })
    })
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hello">
  <h1 style="zoom: 200%; transition: zoom 1s ease-in-out;">hello </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/cgLLhyyu/1/

```
<div id="hello">
    <h1 style="zoom: 200%; transition: zoom 1s ease-in-out;">h<span>ello</span> </h1>
</div>
```

What you need to do is wrap the elements that need to be fade out inside a span. Rest of the code is good

```
$("#hello").animate({
      zoom: "800%",
      left: window.innerWidth / 2
    }, 3000, function() {
      // 4. Pause for 3 seconds
      $(this).delay(3000)
      // 6. zooms out to 200% heading towards left top corner,
      // (logo position) 
      // 7. Fades out when reaching the logo 8. Logo appears
      .animate({
        zoom: "200%",
        left:0
      }, 3000, function() {
        $(this).find('span').fadeOut(); //<--- change here
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$("#hello").animate({
  zoom: "800%",
  left: window.innerWidth / 2
}, 3000, function() {
     $(this).find('span').fadeOut()
  // 4. Pause for 3 seconds
  $(this).delay(3000)
  // 6. zooms out to 200% heading towards left top corner,
  // (logo position) 
  // 7. Fades out when reaching the logo 8. Logo appears
      .animate({
    zoom: "200%",
    left:0
  }, 3000, function() {
    $(this).fadeOut();
  })
})

});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8hbeyt27/)